# Ms Access Graph - Print to PDF

Tags: ms-access, graph, vba

I have a form "frmStats" which displays a graph based on selections made by the user. 
The graph displays correctly on the form, however for print, I have hidden the buttons and user fields.

My problem is that now there are spaces where the buttons would appear.

Is it possible for me to either only print the graph, or perhaps hide the blank spaces where the buttons would appear ?

Any advise on pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated

thank you

Comment: How are you currently hiding the buttons and printing the graph?

Comment: I'm setting the display property of the buttons to "screen only" and printing to PDF using the OUTPUTtoPDF macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the buttons in the form's header / footer, then setting these to display screen only, will remove any white space where they were.